# Using TauDEM with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, installation, taudem

I can't add the TauDEM Tools.tbx to ArcMap 10.6.1. Windows 10 64bit.

> .... taudem tools.tbx is either not designed to run on Windows or it
>   contains and err. ...... error status  0x000012f

Comment: I could/can not add the TauDEM Tools.tbx following the instructions in TauDEM 5.3 QUICK START GUIDE TO USING THE TAUDEM ARCGIS TOOLBOX October 2015.

Comment: I have a workaround using "import arcpy" in a Python window. After the import statement I wrote "tbx='[path to toolbox\toolbox name.tbx]'" followed by "arcpy.ImportToolbox(tbx)" and I now have the TauDEM Tools toolbox in the ArcMap toolbox. Lets see if it works.